# Create a Hive doesn't work in conjunction with WITH statement

Tags: sql, hive, presto

I can't find a way to create a Hive table from a SELECT statement using WITH clause:

```
CREATE TABLE sandbox.test_table2 AS
(
WITH test_table AS (
  SELECT 1 
)
SELECT * FROM test_table
```

I get the exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 3:0 cannot recognise input near 'WITH' 'test_table' 'AS' in create table statement
```

I can run a similar statement in Presto. Is there an alternative syntax in Hive? Can I refactor my create statement somehow to avoid WITH (note that my actual query is more complex than the demonstration example above)?

Comment: If you use CTE only once inside the main query I suppose you could use inner select, like `create table as select * from (select * from table1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the bracket `(`.

```
CREATE TABLE sandbox.test_table2 AS

WITH test_table AS (
  SELECT 1 
)
SELECT * FROM test_table
```

[image]